# In Ubuntu, php function file_put_contents is undefinde

Tags: php, ubuntu

I've installed ubuntu, and php81, but no

```
file_put_contents
```

function it has not. function_exists('file_put_contents') gives also false. Where to install or what must change in php.ini file?

Comment: Maybe the function is disabled for security reasons. Check php.ini for disable_functions

Comment: If you installed ubuntu and PHP 8.1 yourself for personal use it should not come disabled by default. How did you do this installation?